# How to use an UpdatePanel inside a Reapeater ItemTemplate with a HTML Table

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I want to allow the user to edit by data by row, so only need content updated by row. I managed to achieve this by using a `Repeater` with a `UpdatePanel` in the `ItemTemplate`.

### Using a Div

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ctlScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:Repeater ID="ctlMyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRename" runat="server"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                        CommandName="Rename">Rename...</asp:LinkButton>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRename" 
                        EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But, I want to use a table to ensure structure and spacing and CSS styling wasn't doing it for me, but when I use a table everything goes whacky.

### Using a Table

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ctlScriptManager" runat="server" />
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="ctlMyRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"
                                Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRename" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                                CommandName="Rename">Rename...</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRename"
                        EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

What's the best way to solve this problem? I prefer using a table, because I really want to enforce structure without reliance on CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say whacky. Detailing what is actually happening technically would help us help you. :-)

Comment: The whacky result I got in both IE8 and FireFox3 was that the entire repeater contents is repeated above the 'actual' control (of course without the table opening and closing tags) and any asyncpostback triggered only affects this top html. Whacky!

Comment: Since the UpdatePanel renders as a div I understand that using a table results in invalid HTML, but is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three thoughts that may help....

1. Move the update panel to outside the
   repeater control instead of in the
   template...
2. Use the ListView Control but again
   moving the panel outside of the
   template...
3. Perhaps showing us the CSS you have
   tried on the div's and what you want
   so we can help will get you working
   with your first sample using divs
   again...

Comment: Moving the UpdatePanel outside of the Repeater would result in a less effective UI for me. Imagine the data represented by the Repeater as taking 5 seconds to obtain, you wont want to waste 5 seconds each time only one item is removed/renamed.

Using a Div would solve the problem, but I want my columns to resize based on the cell contents. Eg, if the name is long the column grows, if the description is large then its column grows. This is not ideal for CSS if I'm not wrong and a table solves this UI concern for a structured layout. So... going the div route isn't ideal.

Comment: Have you tried adding a style to the div of "display: table-cell;"?

Comment: I did and I could not seem to maintain the structural integrity of the table metaphor when cells need to grow to accomodate data that needs to be wrapped.

Comment: Have you tried putting the table tag in the header & footer template of the repeater control?